# How to check for Python, the key associated with the certificate or not

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, openssl

I know that the blocks modulus in the certificate and private key must be the same if they are related. But how this can be checked by using Python? I am looking for a solution to the OpenSSL library, but I found none. Please tell me the solution, how to understand what the certificate and private key associated with using Python. If the private key is not encrypted in the format PEM, a certificate in PEM format. Preferably using standard libraries. Without using OpenSSL through the subprocess
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Python interface to the OpenSSL library : pyOpenSSL currently in version 0.13.1.

EDIT : The answer to the question...

**Verify that a private key matches a certificate with PyOpenSSL** :

```
import OpenSSL.crypto
from Crypto.Util import asn1

c=OpenSSL.crypto

# The certificate - an X509 object
cert=...

# The private key - a PKey object
priv=...

pub=cert.get_pubkey()

# Only works for RSA (I think)
if pub.type()!=c.TYPE_RSA or priv.type()!=c.TYPE_RSA:
    raise Exception('Can only handle RSA keys')

# This seems to work with public as well
pub_asn1=c.dump_privatekey(c.FILETYPE_ASN1, pub)
priv_asn1=c.dump_privatekey(c.FILETYPE_ASN1, priv)

# Decode DER
pub_der=asn1.DerSequence()
pub_der.decode(pub_asn1)
priv_der=asn1.DerSequence()
priv_der.decode(priv_asn1)

# Get the modulus
pub_modulus=pub_der[1]
priv_modulus=priv_der[1]

if pub_modulus==priv_modulus:
    print('Match')
else:
    print('Oops')
```

*(Source : http://www.v13.gr/blog/?p=325)*

Comment: Actually, I wrote that I was looking for a solution in OpenSSL, but most likely it's not there. I have not found out how to get from the certificate modulus.

Comment: @Budulianin Edited with the answer to your question

Comment: Oh thank you, really works. I have not seen the documentation module Utils ... The documentation was incomplete. I have already solved the problem by bash and OpenSSL, but I wanted to find out a solution for Python. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Budulianin If this is working for you, you could accept the answer and put a usefull -1, so people facing same problem will now that this is a solution !

Comment: There is something I do not understand here, can we dump_privatekey from a pubkey? (cert.get_pubkey()). Does the pubkey contain some information about the private key??? If soemone can redirect me to a tutorial or an article dealing with it, it will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @CamilleG. If I understand correctly with the help of your explanation image. This is the RSA case? the product of the two large prime numbers produces the modulus. I think this is different for ecdsa case, right? Can we convert ecdsa private key to rsa?

Comment: @GuillaumeCisco RSA and ECDSA are like apple and pear. Both are fruits, are the ingredient to delicious cakes but no one ever succeed to change an apple in a pear

Comment: @CamilleG.Thanks a lot, this is far clearer in my mind now. So we can use modulus for the rsa case to verify private key matches a certificate, what can we use for the ecdsa case? Do you have any idea? I'm unsuccessful finding examples and documentation for this case on the web :/

Comment: @GuillaumeCisco The core underlying function doing those kind of checks in OpenSSL is https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_check_private_key.html it says "It merely compares the public materials (e.g. exponent and modulus of an RSA key) and/or key parameters (e.g. EC params of an EC key) of a key pair." For further details, the code source of it is at https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/cae665dfa6ccec743a7f39cf80676d7d2d787e56/crypto/x509/x509_cmp.c#L278

Comment: Hi, I am getting error "'str' object has no attribute 'get_pubkey'" 


My Case:

# The certificate - an X509 object
cert= <Public Certificate value in a variable>

# The private key - a PKey object
priv=...

Answer (score 10):

```
def check_associate_cert_with_private_key(cert, private_key):
    """
    :type cert: str
    :type private_key: str
    :rtype: bool
    """
    try:
        private_key_obj = OpenSSL.crypto.load_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, private_key)
    except OpenSSL.crypto.Error:
        raise Exception('private key is not correct: %s' % private_key)

    try:
        cert_obj = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
    except OpenSSL.crypto.Error:
        raise Exception('certificate is not correct: %s' % cert)

    context = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(OpenSSL.SSL.TLSv1_METHOD)
    context.use_privatekey(private_key_obj)
    context.use_certificate(cert_obj)
    try:
        context.check_privatekey()
        return True
    except OpenSSL.SSL.Error:
        return False
```

source: http://docs.ganeti.org/ganeti/2.14/html/design-x509-ca.html#verify-whether-x509-certificate-matches-private-key

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution without using some SSL library, but if you want a pure pyopenssl solution, you can try this:

```py
from OpenSSL.crypto import load_certificate, load_privatekey, dump_publickey, FILETYPE_PEM

def compare_cert(cert_str, key_str):
    cert = load_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, crt)
    key = load_privatekey(FILETYPE_PEM, key)
    cert_pub = dump_publickey(FILETYPE_PEM, cert.get_pubkey())
    key_pub= dump_publickey(FILETYPE_PEM, key)
    if cert_pub != key_pub:
        print('Error, certificate key does not match provided key')
```

Not sure when `dump_publickey` was added but it seems to work well. I only know this works on python3 with pyopenssl=19.1.0